# How do you change the umask when building with rpmbuild?

Tags: permissions, rpm, umask

I've tried 'umask 77' in the shell, then building it with:

```
[non-root-user@machine SPECS]$ rpmbuild -bb SPECFILE.spec
```

but I still get this from the output:

```
+ umask 022
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the umask from the shell because rpmbuild will always set a a fixed umask of `0022` before running `%prep` script.

Therefore, depending on what you're trying to achieve, you could try change the umask in the spec file, at the beginning the `%prep` section:

```
%prep
umask 077
```

But, if you're just trying to set the file permissions for the files in the RPM, the standard way is to use `%defattr` and `%attr` directives in the `%files` section:

- `%defattr` sets the default attributes for files and folders:

  ```
  %defattr(<file mode>, <user>, <group>, <dir mode>)
  ```

some attributes may be omitted by replacing them with a dash (because the file is installed with those attributes properly set)

- `%attr` sets the attributes for a single file or folder:

  ```
  %attr(<mode>, <user>, <group>) file/folder
  ```

As with `%defattr` if a particular attribute does not need to be specified, you can replace it with a dash (for example you can use it along with `%defattr` to keep the default value for that attribute)

A full example:

```sh
%files
# set default attributes for all files and folders:
%defattr(644, root, root, 755)
# make a file executable:
%attr(755, -, -) /usr/bin/myexec
# set a different owner for a file:
%attr(-, myuser, -) /var/log/mylog.log
# set different permissions, owner and group for a file:
%attr(600, myuser, mygroup) /home/myfile
```

For more details & examples you can take a look to: 
http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-specref-files-list-directives.html and 
http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-anywhere-specifying-file-attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think changing the umask is what you should be doing. I assume you are unhappy with the permissions on the files coming out of the RPM. For that, you should be using `%attr()` and `%defattr()` in your `%files` section.

Comment: Yeah, I just set all my specs to have 755. I am just trying to understand what -,root,root does and why I'd want to even bother with it.

Comment: Because you may want the files to be owned by another user. You would have the files created with the proper mask by the installer of, say, MySQL. Well, you want the files owned by the user "`mysql`" so you would use `%defattr(-,mysql,mysql)` and then only have the files that REALLY need to be root's tagged individually with `%attr()` flags.